# Build everything : even builtByDefault: false

Tags: command-line, qbs

I have a project that contain lots of references to other qbs file.

```
Project {
    name: "MyProject"

    references: ["SubProject1/SubProject1.qbs",
        "SubProject2/SubProject2.qbs",
        "SubProject3/SubProject3.qbs",
        "SubProject4/SubProject4.qbs",
        ...
        ]
}
```

When working in QtCreator, I don't want to always buid everything, so some of the subProject are not built by default :

```
builtByDefault: false
```

I also have automated build tools that should built everything to make sure it does build.

The tools run commands like :

```
/opt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qbs build -d . -f ../MyProject/MyProject.qbs --job
```

Problem is this command doesn't build the subProject that are not build by default.

**Is there a way to force it to build everything in command line ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained in the documentation : https://doc.qt.io/qbs/product-item.html

I simply needed to add **--all-products**

```
<qbs-folder>/qbs build --all-products -d . -f ../MyProject/MyProject.qbs
```